# dual booting windows 7 and ubuntu on a hybrid ssd/hdd

Tags: dual-boot

I am in the process of building a computer with this type of set up.
1 500 GB ssd and 2 hdds one 4TB and one 1 TB

My goal is to use the ssd for the actual operating systems and favourite applications for both windows 7 and ubuntu 13.10

the 4TB hdd for windows 7 data storage and the 1TB hdd for ubuntu 13.10 data storage.

Does anyone know the details for the installation steps for the above set up.

Thanx  in advanced

p.s. I am open to other suggestions if the above ideal is not possible

Comment: Are you planning on BIOS or UEFI? Default Windows DVD only is BIOS which only boots from MBR(msdos) partitioning. I believe you can convert the Windows DVD to flash and modify it for UEFI if desired. Ubuntu will boot in BIOS or UEFI from gpt partitioned drives. Your 4TB drive will have to be gpt partitioned. I also prefer samller system partitions and larger data partitions and gpt partitioning unless you have to have MBR for Windows. I also prefer that every drive be bootable or have a Linux install on every drive just as a backup way to boot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should install Windows 7 on the SSD (assuming you haven't already). Install Ubuntu (dual-boot) onto that disk. (Be sure to create a [system image](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/what-is-a-system-image) and recovery disk in case anything goes wrong.)

You should be able to use both storage HDDs as they are.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

first install Windows however you want.

what you can do for the Ubuntu part is that you make a partition on the ssd and make it your `/` partition. and a partition on the hdd which you make `/home`. You find those options when you click 'something else' option while the install process. I am not sure whether there is a option to install some programs somewhere else than others. but with this setup you will install all programs and Ubuntu on the ssd but the user data will be on the hdd.

You should also make a swap partition. this one is maximum twice as large as your memory and I beleave it is best to place it on a hdd since it are a lot of writes and that might be a problem for a ssd.

If you need more help with how this works I can help you further with that.